# What is 'name="array[]" in the checkbox input declaration of an html/php script?

Tags: php, html, foreach, webforms

In a 'learn mysql' book I'm following there is the following line (simplified... It gets data from a server and does other stuff but I edited it so the main part to focus on is there).

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="todelete[]" />
```

What does it do and is there a name for this kind of syntax?
I'm guessing we don't refer to is like $_POST[todelete[]]

The book uses it in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['todelete'] as $delete_id)
```

I can't pin my finger on it... but something about this isn't clicking in terms of how I've used the name attribute in the past.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply declaring an array to accept multiple answers.

Furthermore, you can use a multi-dimensional array in a form input:

HTML:

```
<input name="data[customer][firstname]" type="text" />
<input name="data[customer][lastname]" type="text" />
```

PHP:

```
$firstname = $_POST['data']['customer']['firstname'];
```

In your example, the data would be stored in `$_POST` as...

```
$_POST['todelete']
```

...which would be an array of checkbox values.

In order for the `foreach` to make sense, you would need to know something about the checkboxes in question in order to do something useful with the data. You could just as easily use...

```
$post = $_POST['todelete'];

$post[0]
$post[1]
... etc.
```

Especially useful is the way that PHP can handle indexed form names. For example, you could have...

```
<input name="employee[0][firstname]" value="John"/>
<input name="employee[0][lastname]" value="Smith"/>

<input name="employee[1][firstname]" value="Joe"/>
<input name="employee[1][lastname]" value="Bloggs"/>
```

And it will return an array of values as `$_POST['employee']`...

```
array (
    0 => array('firstname' => 'John', 'lastname' => 'Smith'),
    1 => array('firstname' => 'Joe', 'lastname' => 'Bloggs'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just an array, and it's interpreted as an array in PHP. You wouldn't access the array like `foo[arr[]]`, but like `foo['arr']` which will give you the array to loop. Think of this for example:

```
$post = array('todelete' => [1,2,3,4]);
$todelete = $post['todelete'];
var_dump($todelete); //=> [1,2,3,4]
```